# Constraint controlled reflective mesh

Tags: rendering, lighting, constraints, reflection

Is there a way to use constraints such that a mesh with reflective material will be at the correct angle to reflect light from a point source to a target object?

Or if not with constraints, is there a way to do this at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your reflector's normal is along its local Z, the easiest way I can think of is to give it 2 consecutive *Damped Track* constraints:

[image]

One to the light, with influence 1, and then another to the target, with influence 0.5.

Then the normal of the reflector (middle ray, below)  will bisect the [light-reflector-target] angle:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! working great! is there any way to show light paths in the viewport for more accurate tweaking?

Comment: Tank you! I guess a little GN setup might be good for that... another question, really?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this by using two track to constraints:

[image: Track to constraint]

Select the light, then the reflector object, then F3 to do a search and select *Track To Constraint*, then do the same thing between the reflector object and the subject object.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong. But don't you want the reflector to _bisect_  the angle between the light and the target?.. Maybe not, for a diffuse reflector...

Comment: You might be right. I am a high-school dropout who got straight D's in math class after all. :P

Comment: I just did some tests to check and you're definitely more right than I am.

Comment: I couldn't be sure, myself, for diffuse reflectors, without looking back at how the diffuse shader works. Thanks for the tests!

Comment: I think your intuition has more to do with the fundamental way light bounces work and less to do with the surface reflectivity. So it should apply to any Principled Shader.